# storeValue and type in selenium ide

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using **Selenium IDE**, and trying to store an email address (that appears in a webpage) and type it in a text box (a gmail new message text field). This is the script I'm using:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeValue</td>
  <td>primary_email</td>
  <td>var_primary_email_to_type</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>setTimeout</td>
  <td>3000</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>open</td>
  <td>https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox?compose=new</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>pause</td>
  <td>2500</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td>//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/textarea</td>
  <td>example@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td>name=subjectbox</td>
  <td>TestUserID</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>pause</td>
  <td>1500</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td>class=editable LW-avf</td>
  <td>${var_primary_email_to_type}</td>
</tr>
```

The value that is typed in the text box is "on", instead of the email address itself.
i also tried to replace the `storeValue` with `store`, and with `storeText`. it still doesn't type the email address.

This is (part of) the html code of the certain page, where I'm trying to store the email address form:

```
<input id="u_16_3" class="uiInputLabelRadio" type="radio" checked="1" value="bdllqim_alisonsky_1381050300@tfbnw.net" name="primary_email>
```

(the email address i want to store is: `bdllqim_alisonsky_1381050300@tfbnw.net`)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Testing using Gmail might be against TOS: "Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide." - see http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/regional.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Get email address stored 
storeText | primary_email | var_primary_email_to_type

now, make sure you have the value you want

echo | ${var_primary_email_to_type}

you can manually execute these steps first to make sure you have the value you want.

then, if the type command won't work to enter the text(assuming you have the email text you want), try using sendkeys or typekeys instead.

Klendathu

Comment: Thanks! the problem was that the target needed to be the class name rather than the element name. i used 'storeText' and 'Type'. the echo command helped me understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store `bdllqim_alisonsky_1381050300@tfbnw.net` form the following HMTL code yes?

`<input id="u_16_3" class="uiInputLabelRadio" type="radio" checked="1" value="bdllqim_alisonsky_1381050300@tfbnw.net" name="primary_email>`

command `storeValue`

Target `id=u_16_3`

Value `mystoreemail`

You want to type in `class=editable LW-avf` yes? If so

command `type`

Target `css=.edittable`

Vale `${mystoreemail}`